# grep pattern matching for case insensitivity

Tags: regex

I wanted to write a grep function to show me all listening ports on my host.

I know how to do it by using the -i function in grep :

```
netstat -a |egrep -i 'listen'
```

But now I wanted to write it in regex :

```
netstat -a |egrep 'm/listen/i'
```

I thought : m because netstat outputs multiple lines and i because it is LISTEN, so I wanted case insensivety.

However this does not give any output. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try perl instead:

```
netstat -an | perl -n -e 'print m/listen/i'
```

I like the [netstat solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/298396/grep-pattern-matching-for-case-insensitivity/298399#298399). 1 Command done and dusted.

Answer (score 5):

You can show all listening ports with:

```
netstat --protocol=ip -nlp
```

About your command, `grep` works line by line. Where did you read this syntax, it seems belong to `sed`.